# Instance of Arbitrary for custom list-like type

Tags: haskell

I have following datatype(like a list):

```
  data List a =
      Nil
    | Cons a (List a)
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

and created an instance for `Monoid`:

```
  instance Monoid (List a) where
    mempty = Nil
    mappend Nil ys = ys
    mappend (Cons x xs) ys = Cons x (mappend xs ys)
```

I try to write an instance for `Arbitrary` for testing latter but could not complete it:

```
  instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (List a) where
    arbitrary = do
```

Help me please to complete the function.

Comment: The simplest way would be to add a function `fromList :: [a] -> List a` and implement it as `fromList arbitrary`. Or do you want to implement it from scratch?

Answer (score 5):

What about using [oneof](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.1.0.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html#v:oneof) function?

```
instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (List a) where
  arbitrary = oneof [pure Nil, Cons <$> arbitrary <*> arbitrary]
```

It will generate either the empty value `Nil` or non-empty list. `oneof` takes the list of `Gen a` values, that's why `pure` and `<$>` with `<*>` needed to wrap the value into `Gen`. `return` and `liftM2` can also be used.

After defining the `instance` what about quickChecking a trivial test:

```
prop_nil_mappend :: List Int -> Bool
prop_nil_mappend xs = mappend Nil xs == xs

main :: IO ()
main = quickCheck prop_nil_mappend
```

By the way in most of cases `Nil` is not as useful as non-empty list, so you can define the frequency of generating of each of these:

```
instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (List a) where
  arbitrary =
    frequency [(1, pure Nil),
               (5, Cons <$> arbitrary <*> arbitrary)]
```

Comment: You should use `sized` instead.

Answer (score 3):

We split this into two functions. First of all, a function where we generate a list of a fixed length:

```
vectorList :: (Arbitrary a) => Int -> Gen (List a)
vectorList n = if n <= 0 
                 then return Nil
                 else Cons <$> arbitrary <*> vectorList (n - 1)
```

Now that we can generate arbitray lists of a fixed size, we can use [`sized`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.10.0.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html#v:sized) to generate lists:

```
instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (List a) where
  arbitrary = sized vectorList
```

This makes sure that we enable QuickCheck to choose the size of the list. Generally, QuickCheck will choose small size parameters first in its test and increase the size. If you were to choose a random size, you might create very long lists where a small list already suffices to check your test case.

Note that `vectorList` is just `replicateM n arbitrary` for your data type. If you provide `fromList :: [a] -> List a`, you can change `vectorList` to

```
vectorList n = fromList (replicateM n arbitrary)
```

But then you can just use

```
instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (List a) where
  arbitrary = fmap fromList arbitrary
```

Comment: I keep wondering if there's some `recursion-schemes`-like way to do this. Something like `replicateM :: (Base t ~ ListF a, Corecursive t, Applicative f) => Int -> f a -> f t`. I think that should actually be doable, but doing it efficiently I think requires `embed` rather than anything higher-level.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
replicateM 0 action = Nil
replicateM n action = Cons <$> action <*> replicateM (n-1) action

instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary [a] where
    arbitrary = do
        length <- getSize
        replicateM length arbitrary
```

This version of `replicateM` is just like [the standard version](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM), except it returns a `List` rather than a `[]`.

Comment: You should use `sized` instead of an arbitrary `length`. Alternatively, use `getSize`.